# NullPointerException on button click

Tags: java, android

I get a NullpointerException error when I click my button.
The logcat indicates that the error is in the line 62

```
String Titre = Title.getText().toString();
```

I think it's because my EditTexts are not initialized, that's why I created the initFields() method, but I still don't know where to call it because wherever I call it i get a NullPointerException too

here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
android.view.View.OnClickListener{

private EditText Title, Description, Coordonnees, Tel, mail;
private Bitmap photo;
private ImageView imageView;
//private PhotoPicker photoPicker;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titre);
    Description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Description);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);
    Coordonnees = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Coordonnees);
    Tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel);
    mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Mail);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //initFields();
    ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.bouton1)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.images)).setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.images:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        break;
    case R.id.bouton1:
        String Titre = Title.getText().toString();
        String Desc = Description.getText().toString();
        String Coord = Coordonnees.getText().toString();
        String tel = Tel.getText().toString();
        String Mailtxt = mail.getText().toString();

        boolean trueMail = Pattern
        .compile("^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(Mailtxt)
                .matches();
        boolean trueTel = Pattern.matches("^[+]?[0-9]{3,}$", tel);

        if (imageView == null || !trueMail || !trueTel || Titre.equals("")
                || Desc.equals("") || Coord.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.missing_field, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.register_photo));
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize=16; //image will be 16x smaller than an original. Note, that it's better for perfomanse to use powers of 2 (2,4,8,16,32..).
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options); 
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);

            imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        }
    }

}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
private void initFields() {
    Title.setText("");
    Description.setText("");
    Coordonnees.setText("");
    Tel.setText("");
    mail.setText("");
}
```

}

Comment: check your Title.getText() for null value.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read.  Please use lower case for first letter of a variables and method names (e.g. `title`, not `Title`) and upper case for first letter of classes and interfaces. `private EditText title, description, coordonnees, tel, mail;`

Answer (score 2):

You should inflate your layout before finding the elements.

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); <-- move this line here
 Title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titre);
 /**/
  //initFields();
```

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) :

> Almost all activities interact with the user, so the `Activity` class
>   takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI
>   with `setContentView(View)`
>
> `/**/`
>
> `onCreate(Bundle)`is where you initialize your activity. Most
>   importantly, here you will usually call `setContentView(int)`with a
>   layout resource defining your UI, and using `findViewById(int)`to
>   retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with
>   programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titre);
    ... // rest of the code
```

You need to inflate the layout first then initialize views. `findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout.  So you need to set the content of the layout to the activity first and then initialize your views.

You have already initialized imageView like below no need to initialize it again

```
  imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);
```

So replace this

```
  ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.images)).setOnClickListener(this);
```

By

```
  imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: My code was like you're saying, I had the setContentView statement before the findViewById statements but in this case i got error in the logcat.
I think the problem is not in the setContentView statement since it works fine on my android phone, but I get the NPE error once I click the button.
I'm trying to get you the logcat, it'll be ready in few minutes

Comment: @ahmedbenfadhel check the ids in xml. chck if you have referenced them properly while initializing your views.

Comment: That's it, I have some mistakes in some IDs and now it works fine thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setContentView` before your intialization of views.

Always keep `setContentView` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


    Title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titre);
    Description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Description);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);
    Coordonnees = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Coordonnees);
    Tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel);
    mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

As some users say, you have to create and set the layout before get views from it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titre);
    Description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Description);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);
    Coordonnees = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Coordonnees);
    Tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel);
    mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Mail);
```

And then you can associate onClickListener to you buttons.